# Horizontal Scroll view is not showing all the images React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a listView where i am using horizontal scroll view to show the gallery. first 13 rows of listView which have gallery is showing perfectly fine but then rest of the images are just blank. only placeholder is there. what can be the reason for that.

```
  <View>
            <ScrollView
              style={styles.container}
              automaticallyAdjustInsets={false}
              horizontal={true}
              decelerationRate={0}
              snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH + CARD_MARGIN*2}
              snapToAlignment="start"
              contentContainerStyle={styles.contentT}
              pagingEnabled={true}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            >

            {_this.props.media.first_five_photos.map(function(photo) {
              return (<View style={[{width:width,  height: _this.props.media.height},styles.card]} key={photo.id}>
               <Text>
                 <Image
                 source={{uri: photo.image_url}}
                 style={{width:width,  height: _this.props.media.height}}/>
               </Text>
             </View>)
            })}

              </ScrollView>
              <View style={{position: "absolute",right: 15, top: (this.props.media.height/2)-20}}>
                <Text >
                  <Image style={{height: 30,width:30}} source={require("../assets/white-img-slide.png") }/>
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
```

Comment: Check the uri, width and height of images if they are fine?

Comment: everything is here when i do with single images it works or when i repeat single images it works but with dynamic url. it returns just blank.

Comment: could you make test app here https://rnplay.org/ ?

Comment: Can you add onError prop in Image to see if there is any error. Also you should switch to ListView instead of plain Scrollview. Displaying multiple images is not efficient in scrollview.

Comment: @while1 Can react-native support horizontal listView. if yes please provide reference. and i tried onError props. did not get any error. my problems seem to relate with that https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/289. do you have answer for that

Comment: @Waleed Arshad Yes. ListView scan support horizontal scroll. You can provide renderScrollComponent prop of ListView as ScrollView with horizontal scroll enabled.

Comment: @while1 i'm also facing the same problem but if i remove the parent of scrolview in this case view it works fine....did you guys found any solution....

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview has removeClippedSubviews property. Maybe it will help you
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#removeclippedsubviews

Comment: could you make test app here rnplay.org ?